# Debugging multiple files in DrRacket

Tags: debugging, scheme, racket

I am using DrRacket to debug scheme code using the R5RS language.  I am trying to debug over multiple files imported using the load function.  I opened both files as the instructions on the Dr Racket site says but when debugging, functions from other files are just skipped over.

Any idea of how to debug multiple files in DrRacket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, the debugger cannot go over files other than the one in the definitions window.

(In addition, using the R5RS language and `load` is a bad way to organize code -- using [modules](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-basics.html) is much better.)